# Lead creation based on a trigger

Tags: trigger, leads

my requirement is based on some conditions leads coming from website should be created as a secondary lead after 24 hours of the created date.
my code is

```
trigger CreateLead on Lead (before insert, after update) 
{

    List<Lead> conttoinsert = new List<Lead>();
    List<Lead> conttoinsert1 = new List<Lead>();

    for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
     {

           if (lead.LeadSource == 'Website' && lead.Lead_Source_Website__c != 2015' && lead.Universe__c == TRUE) 
        {
            Lead con = new Lead();
            con.FirstName   = lead.firstname;
            con.LastName   = lead.lastname;
            con.salutation = lead.salutation;
            con.title         = lead.title;
            con.Company    = lead.company;
            con.Status     = lead.Status;
            con.Phone       = lead.Phone;
            con.MobilePhone     = lead.MobilePhone;
            con.Fax   = lead.Fax;
            con.LeadSource   = lead.LeadSource;
            con.Rating = lead.Rating;
            con.Website = lead.Website;
            con.Secondary_Lead__c = TRUE;
            con.Lead_Source_Detail__c = Dubai';

            conttoinsert.add(con); // For Bulk processing of the Records.
        } //end if
    } 
        insert conttoinsert;

         {
            for (Lead lead : Trigger.new)
           if (lead.LeadSource == 'Website' && lead.Lead_Source_Website__c != 'Kuwait' && lead.KUWAIT__c == TRUE) 
        {
            Lead con1 = new Lead();
            con1.Lastname   = lead.lastname;
            con1.company    = lead.company;
            con1.Status     = lead.Status;
            con1.Firstname   = lead.firstname;
            con1.Phone       = lead.Phone;
            con1.MobilePhone     = lead.MobilePhone;
            con1.Lead_Source_Detail__c  = 'Kuwait';
            conttoinsert1.add(con1); // For Bulk processing of the Records.
        } //end if
    } 
        insert conttoinsert1;


}
```

Now when I create a lead, in total 9 leads are getting created. I am not sure whats wrong with my code. it should suppose to create only 3 leads based on my condition.
Please help.

Comment: Can you provide details about the lead you are creating? Also why would it create three lead if you inserting a single lead? There are only 2 inserts.

Comment: first lead is created from website, 2nd and 3rd lead should create based on 2 individual checkboxes. Suppose the lead coming from website has 2 checkboxes = TRUE, then in total it should create 3 leads ( 1 coming from website, 2 and 3 are based on the checkboxes.) the 2 and 3 leads will have a copy of all lead details from 1). please let me know if it is not clear. thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that there are no more triggers/workflows/process builders on lead? It seeems that records that you insert may fire the same trigger again (by updating records -- after update for example)

Comment: Your code is definitely not getting into a recursive loop as per the code. Check one thing, do you have any workflow which updates leads? And how are you managing the 24 hours delay?

Comment: 24 hours delay is not included in this code. if the logic works then I will include. but I am unable to figure out why it is creating 5 leads. how to get into recursive loop. there is no workflow which updates leads. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting lead record in the lead trigger Thats causing a **recusive loop**.

Thats why it is creating 9 records. Also there are many other loops in your code which is affecting your functionality. Like why are you doing 2 dml for inserting Lead records. Just check size of list and then insert it.

```
If(conttoinsert.size() > 0)
    insert conttoinsert;
```

Also you can stop this recursive behavior using Boolean variable and also follow some other best practices.

1. [Triger Best Practices](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Trigger_Frameworks_and_Apex_Trigger_Best_Practices)
2. [Triger Best Practices 2](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_bestpract.htm)

Comment: If trigger is going in a recursive loop, then why it is not throwing an error? It can go only utpo 5 level deep.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how are you managing 24 delay using your code.

However regarding your code, in your trigger you are inserting 2 new leads for each new lead creation. Therefore total 6 new leads will be created for 3 leads you are inserting, resulting into total 9 leads (6+3).

As you are not populating "Lead_Source_Website__c" field in for you leads generated in the code, trigger is not going in a recursive loop.

Comment: Hi , How to stop creating more multiple leads in this code. because it is creating 9 leads for one lead.